# SQl Server trigger can't rollback a change

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

To prevent creating \ altering an SQL login with CHECK_POLICY=OFF I've created a server trigger:

```
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [create_or_alter_login] ON ALL SERVER
FOR CREATE_LOGIN, ALTER_LOGIN
as
begin
    DECLARE @data xml
    DECLARE @text nvarchar(max);
    DECLARE @user nvarchar(max);
    DECLARE @object_name nvarchar(max);
    DECLARE @MESSAGE_LOG varchar(255);
    DECLARE @MESSAGE_PRINT varchar(255);
    
    SET @data = EVENTDATA();
    SET @text = @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)');
    SET @user = @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/LoginName)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)');
    SET @object_name = @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)');
    IF(@text LIKE N'%CHECK_POLICY=OFF%')
    BEGIN
        SET @MESSAGE_LOG = 'XXX Policy: CHECK_POLICY=OFF is a forbidden setting. Rollback for a batch ' + @text 
        exec xp_logevent 60000, @MESSAGE_LOG , warning
        SET @MESSAGE_PRINT  = '
        ************************************************************
        ' + 'XXX Policy: CHECK_POLICY=OFF is a forbidden setting.
        ' + 'Rollback SQL login change for '+ @object_name + '
        ************************************************************
        '
        Rollback
        RAISERROR (@MESSAGE_PRINT,10,1)
        
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @MESSAGE_LOG = 'SQL Login has been created or changed: ' + @text
        exec xp_logevent 60000, @MESSAGE_LOG , informational
    END

end
```

It's functioning if I use t-sql or SSMS, but if dbatools Commandlets to copy or to create a login are used it's still possible to create a login.
Is this a trigger code issue and my error or does SQL powershell modules use non-transactional creating of database objects? Are there any ways to catch and rollback it?

Thank you!

Comment: What T-SQL does dbatools Commandlets issue? What security context does it run under?

Comment: I run it on my test system as an active directory user with sa permissons. Unfortunately even after multiple profiler traces I didn't see the exact t-sql statement ("replaced for a security reasons, means Profiler), only an event message about it and it's a standard t.-sql: ```CREATE LOGIN [XXXX] WITH PASSWORD=0x****** HASHED, SID=XXXXX, DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF```

Comment: I can guess at two things: 1. The trigger is first being disabled; 2. It's using a DAC. These seem over the top, and you should see some sign of it in the SQL Server Log. In fact I suggest a quick peek in there

Comment: Thank you for a quick reply!
Trigger is active, I can see messages in SQL and event log created by it. As a windows server has a firewall ON and DAC port is not open I'm not sure it's possible. My guess is SMO used by powershell running kind of "transaction-less" changes, but I do not have any additional information on it.